# How to send event from nested inner class in Java

Tags: java, react-native, inner-classes, sender

I have outer `public class ClassifierModule` and inner `public class ClassifierRunnable`. How to send `int` from inner class and receive it in outer one?
Here is my code:

```
//outer class
public class ClassifierModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements BufferListener {

    public ClassifierModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        appState = ((MainApplication)reactContext.getApplicationContext());
        }     

    @Override
    public String getName() {
      return "Classifier";
    }

    // Called to emit events to event listeners in JS
    private void sendEvent(String eventName, int result) {
        getReactApplicationContext()
           .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
           .emit(eventName, result);
    }

    //inner class        
    public class ClassifierRunnable implements Runnable {

        public ClassifierRunnable(double[][] buffer) {
            rawBuffer = buffer;
            PSD = new double[NUM_CHANNELS][nbBins];
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (noisePresent(rawBuffer)) {
                Log.w("ConcentrationTracker", "noise");

                return;
            }

            else if(isTracking) {
                getSmoothPSD(rawBuffer);

                bandMeans = bandExtractor.extract1D(PSD);

                // Concentration algorithm goes here
                int score = measureRatio(bandMeans);

                Log.w("ConcentrationTracker", "Concentration score" + score);

                sendEvent("CONCENTRATION_SCORE", score);
            }

            else if(isLogging) {
                getSmoothPSD(rawBuffer);

                bandMeans = bandExtractor.extract1D(PSD);

                int a = measureAlpha(bandMeans);
                int b = measureBeta(bandMeans);

                String csvLine = a + "," + b;

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: *why* is the real question. This is really a sign of an awful design

Comment: The answer is: because it is working app that I want to modify and it's so complicated that I wont mess with its design ;) But I really need to call those int somehow.

Comment: Where is `sendEvent` defined? Does that not already do what you need?

Comment: It is defined in outer class, but it sends event for javascript. Can I use that too? I updated my question and added sendEvent code

Comment: Yes, you can... I'm guessing you've not had a formal education with Java method calls and inheritance?

Comment: You're right, I'm newbie ;) I roughly know how it functions but I've still much to learn. And asking and practising is the best way to study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you already have a function that does this... Just intercept the integer

```
private void sendEvent(String eventName, int result) {
  System.out.println("Got " + result);
  // other code 
}
```

Comment: Ok, if I add `System.out.println("Got " + result);` to the code, how do I use `result` in other method?

Comment: You call a different method... After all, println is also just "another method"

Comment: Thank you! But I'm still not able to save it as log. How should it look like? `logger.info(???);` Maybe `logger.info("Got " + result);` instead of `System.out.println("Got " + result);`?

Comment: I don't know what logging framework you have, but that looks fine

Comment: I'm using logback-android. It looks fine but unfortunately doesn't work...

Comment: I might suggest that you post a new question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a method in outer class which accept the int value and call it from inner class. This way you can transfer data to outer class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ;) Do you have any example how to do that?

Comment: public class OuterClass {

 int outerClassval;

 void setVal(int val) {
  this.outerClassval = val;
 }

 int getVal() {
  return this.outerClassval;
 }

 private class InnerClass {
  void setOuterClassVal(int val) {
   setVal(val);
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
  InnerClass inner = outer.new InnerClass();
  inner.setOuterClassVal(22);
  System.out.println(outer.getVal());
 }
}